# What AC Router would allow for multiple SSIDs?

Tags: router

I'm looking for a router to support up to 20 users for a small startup, that would allow configuring at least 2 different networks + 1 guest network.

I guess my question is how, or where, should I locate or identify something that would satisfy these requirements. A simple google search for `multipli-SSID router` provides a slew of non-relevant answers, and this parameter does not appear to be in the usual specs provided easily. Any other search terms that might help?

I can't seem to find documentation that details which routers support this out-of-the-box.

Comment: Some from MikroTik could help.
Multiple SSID on RB751U-2HnD - guidance [here](http://wiki.mikrotik.com/images/5/5f/Create_Virtual_AP_for_Campus.pdf)

Comment: **Requests for product, service, or learning material recommendations** are considered [**off-topic**](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) on serverfault.com. Potentially your question can be reworded or made suitable for the  [Hardware Recommendations](http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) Stack Exchange community, but before posting, please read their guidelines. Alternatively Wikipedia often has lists of available products.

Comment: It sounds like what you want/need is simply classified as a professional/enterprise WiFi router/AP, not a consumer model. You might want to use VLAN support as discriminator to identify models with "advanced" (enterprise) features.